# Squarespace code injecting

Tags: code-injection, squarespace

I injected `<script>` tags into my squarespace template making the `<main>` `display:none`. Now I cannot edit that section through squarespace because it is gone. Recommendations how to get it back without starting from scratch?

`$( "#page" ).css( "display", "none" );`

was the code I injected into the HTML.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to understand what you are asking, but i'll assume that you added that single line of code, it hides everything when you navigate to your site page, and you are not sure how to go back to the adminstration page to remove that line of code?

You used "code injection" to insert that code. You can go back to that same code injection location and remove that line of code. The [squarespace manual has documentation on code injection](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815908-Using-Code-Injection). If you are not sure where to go to get back to the administration pages, you can enter a url like this: `https://<yoursite>/config` for example: `https://mysquarespacesite.com/config`

Answer (score 0):

For your problem I have one solution using Chrome inspector console tool(inbuilt tool of Chrome browser), make sure you open your website on Chrome browser with login to your squarespace website and follow these steps:

1. On your website homepage for example: `https://<yoursite>/config`, Click F12 from your keyboard **OR** right click using mouse  and click on **Inspect** which will show you inspector mode of Chrome browser
2. Go to Console tab from inspector tool
3. Paste following code into Console:

> document.getElementById('page').style.display = "block";

4. Hit enter and your `<main>` tag will be set as display block
5. Now your `<main>` section should be visible, go to code injection of your website and permanently remove **display : none** which will fix your website hiding `<main>` section problem for forever

> Following are pictures of every step:

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

Note: I have tested this code into demo template of Squarespace website: https://bedford-demo.squarespace.com

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code. Your code will execute only when you are not logged in as administrator.

```
if (window.top.location.href == window.self.location.href) {
    $("#page").css("display", "none");
}
```